# DPDK buffers received from the RX ring and freeded on the TX path

Tags: dpdk

Consider a DPDK program where each EAL thread:

- receives a packet on its own RX queue
- modifies the buffer in place
- puts it back on the TX ring to echo it back to the sender

The RX buffers are not explicitely freeed as they are re-used on the TX ring. Is it good practice to depend on the TX queue to be processed by the NIC to free up entries in the RX ring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffers successfully put in the Tx queue will be freed by the PMD. That’s the only option, so yes it’s a good practice.

Please note though, that placing a burst of packets in the Tx queue might fail, as the queue might be full for some reason. So if there are any packets left unqueued after `rte_eth_tx_burst()`, those must be freed manually or the transmission must be retried.

Comment: In case modifying the buffer in place takes a long time, I guess the buffer on the RX ring would not be available for the PMD to write data to during all this time? Same if the hardware takes a long time to process the TX ring, right? In that case, is that effectively reducing the size of the RX ring?

Comment: If modification takes a lot, and there are no more free buffers in the Rx queue, packets might be dropped by the NIC. There is an `imissed` counter for that in the stats. Note, if the modification is the bottleneck, there is nothing we can do: any size queue will be eventually filled and packets will be dropped...